# Windows: How to intercept/hook FastIO filesystem calls?

Tags: windows, file-io, filesystems, driver, wdk

I've developed a DLL library that intercepts calls to `NtQueryInformationFile()` - mainly by using mhook. Unfortunately calls for the file information class `FileBasicInformation` are resolved by FastIO calls instead of regular IRP's. So my intercept library isn't called.

I want to archive that a particular application does the file sorting in a different way by changing `ChangeTime`, `LastAccessTime`, `LastWriteTime` and `CreationTime`.

FastIO (instead of IRP's) calls are only used when a few boundary conditions are met, so I tried unmet some of these conditions - but I failed.

These boundary conditions are

- Synchronous file system operation
- Caching is initiated

Caching for file information class `FileBasicInformation` makes no sense to me and I couldn't find a way to intercept library calls to make (or simulate) a asynchronous file system operation of the upper target application.

I'm looking for a way that my DLL library is called even for file information class `FileBasicInformation`, either by

- Intercepting FastIO calls
- Unmet FastIO boundary conditions

I've no clue (and googling does not provide more information) how to intercept FastIO calls.

Or how to unmet FastIO boundary conditions.

Has someone experience in this area and can give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: mhook in kernel mode ?! you really need implement minifilter driver. and you will have [`PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/ns-fltkernel-_flt_callback_data) on any operation. simply check `Flags` for `& FLTFL_CALLBACK_DATA_FAST_IO_OPERATION`